# Hopf theorem for non-orientable manifold

Tags: differential-geometry

I have an exercise which says that :extend the Hopf-Poincare theorem for non-orientable manifold with the indication using the double covering. I have got stuck for long time, so I don't know if somebody can help me. Any answer is greatly appreciated.

Comment: 1) Pull the vector field back to the double cover 2) apply the orientable Poincaré-Hopf theorem 3) divide by two. Since the index is local in nature, this won't change the index of a zero (and each original zero corresponds to two zeroes on the double cover). The Euler characteristic is multiplicative with respect to $n$-sheeted coverings.